# What are good journals for publishing a paper?

Tags: paper-review

I wish  to publish my research work. But do not have a good idea about how and where to publish.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to academics.se.

Comment: It's difficult to give any advice without knowing your field or the type of problems you are working on.